# C++ - my program stops running `freopen` function from <cstdio>

Tags: c++, debugging, freopen, cstdio

In my `main.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include "hashtable.h"

int main() {
    printf("1hello");
    freopen("2.txt", "w", stdout);
    printf("2hello");
    freopen("1.txt", "r", stdin);
    printf("3hello");
    int type;
    char buffer[1000];int data;
    hashtable table(10000, new naive_hashing(), new linear_probe());
    while (true) {
        scanf("%d", &type);
        if (type == 0) {
            scanf("%s", buffer);scanf("%d", &data);
            table.insert(hash_entry(buffer, data));
        }
        else if (type == 1) {
            scanf("%s", buffer);
            printf("%d\n", table.query(buffer));
        }
        else break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`1.txt`:

```
0 dhu_try 3039
0 shirin 3024
0 SiamakDeCode 2647
0 huanghansheng 233
1 dhu
1 dhu_try
1 shirin
1 siamakdecode0
1 huanghansheng
2
```

`output`:

```
1hello
```

As you can see the program paused after it entered the first `freopen` function. I have checked the document already and still yet cannot find the reason why it stopped running. Can anyone help me please? :pleading_face:

Comment: Someone who knows `freopen()` will likely come along, but why not use [`<fstream>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/fstream)? Or [`<iostream>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/istream) for that matter? I'm not convinced that this is a C++ question/program at all.

Comment: What do you see in `2.txt` after you've executed the program? I would expect all the `printf` outputs after `freopen("2.txt", "w", stdout);` to be in that file.

Comment: I'm curious: as part of learning C++, how exactly did you become aware of `freopen` and `scanf`? Last time something similar was the subject matter here it was determined that the source of bad knowledge was an incompetent C++ instructor. Are you in the same boat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You redirected all output to `stdout` to the file `2.txt` when you did

```
freopen("2.txt", "w", stdout);
```

That's why no `printf` outputs are shown on the console after that `freopen`. Look in the file `2.txt` and you will most probably see the output there - if the `freopen` succeeded. Always check if functions that can fail have succeeded.